# How to create multiple dataframes from a dictionary containing lists of lists

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, dictionary

I have a complex dictionary, such as the below

```
d = {'a':[['x','y'],['1','2']],'b':[['x','y'],['3','4']]}
```

I want to convert it into a set of pd dataframes in a loop, such as

```
a
x y
1 2

b
x y
3 4
```

Any suggestions how that can be accomplished?

Comment: What are those DataFrames? is `a` the name of the index?

Comment: Did you try doing exactly what you said, iterating over the dictionary? I’m not sure that those lists will be interpreted correctly, however.

Comment: Whata have you tried ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the first list as columns name and the rest as rows

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'a': [['x', 'y'], ['1', '2'], ['1', '2'], ['1', '2'], ['1', '2']],
     'b': [['x', 'y'], ['3', '4'], ['3', '4'], ['3', '4'], ['3', '4']]}

# create dict of dataframes with dict comprehension
df_dict = {k: pd.DataFrame(v[1:], columns=v[0]) for k, v in d.items()}

# iterate through df_dict
for k, v in df_dict.items():
    print(k)
    print(v)

#############
a
   x  y
0  1  2
1  1  2
2  1  2
3  1  2
b
   x  y
0  3  4
1  3  4
2  3  4
3  3  4
```